# error in type conversion in operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a template class and I need to overload operator ==. I do this in the following way

```
template <typename T>
class Polynomial {
    vector<T> coefficients;

    public:
    Polynomial(vector<T> c);

    bool operator ==(const Polynomial& second) const {
            const typename vector<T>::iterator thisBegin = this->coefficients.begin();
            const typename vector<T>::iterator secondBegin = second.coefficients.begin();
            for ( ; ((thisBegin != this->coefficients.end()) &&
                                    (secondBegin != second.coefficients.end()));
                            ++thisBegin, ++secondBegin) {
                    if (*thisBegin != *secondBegin)
                            return false;
            }
            while (thisBegin != this->coefficients.end()) {
                    if (*thisBegin != 0)
                            return false;
                    ++thisBegin;
            }
            while (secondBegin != second.coefficients.end()) {
                    if (*secondBegin != 0)
                            return false;
                    ++secondBegin;
            }
            return true;
    }
};
```

However, when I create two objects of this class with T=int and try to apply  this operator

```
Polynomial<int> first(firstVector);
Polynomial<int> second(secondVector);
std::cout << (first == second) << std::endl;
```

I got the error

```
problem2.cpp: In instantiation of ‘bool Polynomial<T>::operator==(const Polynomial<T>&)    const [with T = int; Polynomial<T> = Polynomial<int>]’:
problem2.cpp:63:32:   required from here
problem2.cpp:23:83: error: conversion from ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >}’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >}’ requested
```

Can someone point out what's wrong with this conversion? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to convert a `const_iterator` to an `iterator`:

```
const typename vector<T>::iterator thisBegin = this->coefficients.begin();
```

`this` is `const` in this context, so `this->coefficients.begin();` returns a `const_iterator`. Try this:

```
typename vector<T>::const_iterator thisBegin = this->coefficients.begin();
```

Note also that `thisBegin` is not `const`, as in your example. This is because you then do this kind of thing:

```
++secondBegin;
```

which requires the `const_iterator` to be non-const (meaning you can modify the iterator, but not the thing it points to).

Answer (score 1):

- your method is `const` that mean that you can only call `const` functions on `this` and
- you passing `const` reference to method,  so you can only call `const` functions on it

So, both

```
 this->coefficients.begin();
 second.coefficients.begin()
```

returns const iterators.

You cannot assign them to non-`const` ones.

There is a solution:

```
vector<T>::const_iterator& thisBegin = this->coefficients.begin();
vector<T>::const_iterator& secondBegin = second.coefficients.begin();
```

(use references to `const_iterator`)

Even better:

```
auto& thisBegin = this->coefficients.begin();
auto& secondBegin = second.coefficients.begin();
```

(use references to `auto`, C++11 feature)

BTW, you can simply compare two vectors using [`std::mismatch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch)

Comment: Your examples leave you with dangling references.

Comment: @juanchopanza Whoops! Where? =)

Comment: `vector<T>::const_iterator& thisBegin = this->coefficients.begin();` and others.

Comment: @juanchopanza Okay, I've guess it, but why?

Comment: Because `begin()` and `end()` return rvalues. They are temporaries, so you must make copies of them.

Comment: So, I need to refresh my STL knowledge... Thanks gods I've never used references like this before =)